# How to remove an Input Field using Css display:none with javascript className

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to remove some input field in form on HTML using Javascript with the CSS.  The idea is that i want to make both the sign up and log in on the same page,

HTML:

```
   <h3 class="login">
   <a class="tab1" href="#login-tab"  onclick ="log_in()"> Log In </a>
   </h3>
</div>

//FORM FIELD

<div class="input-container">
   <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="usrnm">
</div>

<div class="input-container">
    <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Email" 
    name="email">
</div>

<div class="input-container">
    <input class="input-field" type="password" placeholder="Enter Your 
    Password" name="psw">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
d_none {display:none;}
```

Javascript:

```
function log_in () {
    let inputs =  document.querySelectorAll(.input-container);

    setTimeout( function() {
    for( let d= 0; d < inputs.length ; d++  ) {
        if (d == 0){
            document.querySelectorAll('.input-container')[d].className = "input-container d_block";
        }
        else if (d == 2) {
           document.querySelectorAll('.input-container')[d].className = 
           "input-container d_block"; 
        }
        else {
            document.querySelectorAll('.input-container')[d].className= "input-container d_none";
        }
    }
},200 );
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/djtush/pen/VNXrgx

Comment: what's the purpose of the setTimeout?

Comment: Just to add some Time delay for some kind of animation

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use php for this task. Here is my solution. I will explain it down below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sign In</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="?x=signin">Sign In</a><a href="?x=signup">Sign Up</a>
    <?php $x = $_GET['x']; if ($x == "signin"){ ?>
    <form class="" action="" method="post">
      <h1>Sign In</h1>
      <input type="text" name="" placeholder="username">
      <input type="text" name="" placeholder="password">
    </form>
  <?php } $x = $_GET['x']; if ($x == "signup"){?>
    <form class="" action="" method="post">
      <h1>Sign Up</h1>
      <input type="text" name="" placeholder="create username">
      <input type="text" name="" placeholder="create password">
    </form>
  <?php } ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Above is my code. You will notice there are two PHP if statements and one variable. The variable is storing what is in the link after the question mark and x, if the link is this: nameoffile.php?x=**signin**, $x will store signin. The $_GET checks for any thing storing something in the link like: nameoffile.php?**x**=signin. In this case it is checking what x is storing. The variable in our php, $x, is storing what the x in our link is storing. So the if statements are pretty self explanatory if x = signin it will show signin vise versa. If you don't know php and are confused, check out the reference for get(the thing that check for stuff being stored) [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) and for if statements check [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php). Comment any questions you have.

Comment: @tush let me try this with js, i have some learning to do. if you want to try it yourself I would start off by searching **how to store variables in a link js**. It shoud  end up something like my php, an if statement checking the url. good luck

Answer (score 0):

You should really use some classes or IDs for the elements you want to target. If you change the order of the elements at any time, this code will no longer work the way you expect it to.

Also, I don't understand the reason for the setTimeout, but I've kept it, as per the sample code.

Also, you have 3 containers in your sample HTML, and more in your codepen example.

If you insist on not using classes or IDs, you could go around like this:

```
function log_in () {
    setTimeout( function() {

        let inputs =  document.getElementsByClassName(input-container);

        for(let d=0; d<inputs.length; d++) {
            if (d == 0 || d == 2) { // mark the index of those which should be visible
                inputs[d].className.remove('d_none');
            } else { // the rest will become hidden
                inputs[d].className.add('d_none');
            }
        }
    }
}, 200 );
```

Comment: Using .add or .remove happens when classList is used in raw javascript. I am using className, not sure className.remove or className.add will work